# Modifying xml with System.Xml.XmlDocument PreserveWhitespace property is adding extra space before end tag

Tags: powershell

I am modifying below xml with System.Xml.XmlDocument and setting PreserveWhitespace property to true before load but when I save it, its adding an extra space before end tag.

XML:
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="twCustomerSettings.config">
        <add key="HubUserName" value="" />
        <add key="HubPassword" value="" />
        <add key="IgnoreHubCertErrors" value="false" />
        <add key="NounVerbMetaSetsDirectory" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\AHS\NounVerbMetaData\"/>
        <add key="HOSTNAME_WHITELIST" value="127.0.0.1,::1:,::1" />
        <add key="impersonate" value="false" />
        <add key="securityMode" value="Transport" />
        <add key="QueryBuilder" value="enabled" />
        <add key="iHealthProxyClinicalDocument.ClinicalDocument" value="http://localhost/iHealthProxy/ClinicalDocument.asmx" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

`

Script:

```
$WhitelistServersIPs = "10.131.42.202,10.25.1.25,10.135.0.33"
$ISAPIWebConfigFilePath = "C:\web.config"

$ISAPIConfig = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$ISAPIConfig.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$ISAPIConfig.Load($ISAPIWebConfigFilePath)
$HOSTNAME_WHITELIST = $ISAPIConfig | Select-XML –Xpath "//*[@key='HOSTNAME_WHITELIST']"

Write-Host "Updating HOSTNAME_WHITELIST....."
$HOSTNAME_WHITELIST.Node.Value = $WhitelistServersIPs
$ISAPIConfig.Save($ISAPIWebConfigFilePath)
Write-Host "File updated and saved....."
```

Please note that NounVerbMetaSetsDirectory key do not have space before /> closing tag, while all other nodes have it. After saving the file an extra space is added and line becomes below. I want to preserver exact formatting as it was before.

`<add key="NounVerbMetaSetsDirectory" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\AHS\NounVerbMetaData\" />`

Comment: After saving the file you are expecting the output something like below, <add key="NounVerbMetaSetsDirectory" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\AHS\NounVerbMeta"/>

Comment: yes that is correct @ng-suhas, it's adding a space before closing tag.

Comment: The content of the config file is static right? That's not going to change dynamically?

Comment: Why, exactly, do you worry about extra whitespace in XML element? The standard allows for it, and it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @ng-suhas yes the content is static.

Comment: @vonPryz xml file is provided by another team and we don't want to make any changes apart from what was provided in the document, as part of the deployment process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent extra whitespace is, unfortunately, going to require a lot of effort. `XMLDoucment.Save()` calls .Net internal methods and seems to end up in [`XmlTextWriter.cs`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,ee2f831c11636787). Over there, it's got a hard coded space before slash:

```
    void WriteEndStartTag(bool empty) {
        ...
        xmlEncoder.EndAttribute();
        if (empty) {
            textWriter.Write(" /"); // space-slash
        }
        textWriter.Write('>');
    }
```

If you *really* need to get rid of that space, roll your own XML serializer, or edit the file as text instead of XML. The latter alternative ignores XML validation, so be extra careful not to wreck the config file.